# Call DialogFragment from a custom Fragment, then set its property

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services, android-dialogfragment, google-plus-signin

After having successfully followed the guide [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), I am trying to move all the Google+ related code from my `MainActivity` to a separate custom [GoogleFragment](https://gist.github.com/afarber/0fa3346e570645e74c19).

However I am stuck at the very last spot - in my custom Fragment, I don't know how to access the `mResolvingError` field after the `DialogFragment` has been dismissed:

```
public class GoogleFragment extends Fragment
        implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private boolean mResolvingError = false; // HOW TO ACCESS?

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mResolvingError) {
            // Already attempting to resolve an error.
            return;
        } else if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mResolvingError = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
                if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Show dialog using GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog()
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            mResolvingError = true;
        }
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        // Create a fragment for the error dialog
        ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        // Pass the error that should be displayed
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARGS_DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG_DIALOG_ERROR);
    }

    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
            int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(ARGS_DIALOG_ERROR);
            return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(
                    this.getActivity(),
                    errorCode,
                    REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mResolvingError = false; // DOES NOT COMPILE
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do here please?

If I make the `ErrorDialogFragment` non-static I get compile error:

> This fragment inner class should be static
>   (GoogleFragment.ErrorDialogFragment)

If I keep it static - I can not access the variable either.

I am thinking of 2 workarounds for my problem:

1. Using `LocalBroadcastManager` to send a custom `Intent` from `ErrorDialogFragment` to `GoogleFragment`
2. Define a custom method in `GoogleFragment` and access it through `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()`

But is there maybe a simpler solution?

**UPDATE:**

I've changed the `mResolvingError` field to public and have tried this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        GoogleFragment f = (GoogleFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(GoogleFragment.TAG);
        if (f != null && f.isVisible()) {
            f.mResolvingError = false;
        }
    }
```

but I am not sure how to test this properly and if `f.isVisible()` is needed there...

**UPDATE 2:**

Maybe I should somehow use [DialogInterface.OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) with [GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) in my code?

Comment: You should do it the other way around: the callee must send back the result to the caller. For this, make the caller implement a listener interface so that the callee uses it to communicate the result. If the caller is an Activity, your callee Fragment can retrieve it with `getActivity()`. If the caller is a Fragment, use `setTargetFragment()` on the callee when creating it and `getTargetFragment()` will allow you to retrieve the caller.

Comment: Unfortunately can not use `setTargetFragment()` in my minSdkLevel 9 app... Also, I am confused: the inner class should be static, so that `GoogleFragment` (with its complicated life cycle) does not hold reference to `ErrorDialogFragment`. But if I use interfaces pattern - then there will be reference between them, through the `mListener` variable.

Comment: You can use every Fragment method from API 4 if you use the support library (as you should). All fragment classes must be static because the framework must be able to instanciate them by invoking the empty public constructor. You must not hold the reference to the listener, you must use `getTargetFragment()` or `getActivity()` instead. The references will be cleared when the Fragment is detached from the Activity and reinitialized properly when the fragment is restored and re-attached. This happens for example when you change the screen orientation.

Comment: So you suggest adding `dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this)` and then in the static inner class `ErrorDialogFragment` calling a public method of `GoogleFragment` (found by calling `getTargetFragment`) to set the `mResolvingError=false`?

Comment: Yes exactly. But to make it work properly you should also persist and restore this boolean with the saveInstanceState (again, when the activity is re-created, you lose your state variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BladeCoder's comments have been very insightful, thanks.

However I have realized, that all the hassle with saving and restoring `mResolvingError` is unnecessary, because [startResolutionForResult()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) starts a separate Activity anyway and obstructs my app - so it doesn't really matter if I rotate device or not.

Here is my final code to initiate GCM and fetch Google+ user data -

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1972;
public static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLUS_LOGIN = 2015;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        startRegistrationService();
}

private void startRegistrationService() {
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int code = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (code == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        onActivityResult(REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES, Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(code) &&
        api.showErrorDialogFragment(this, code, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES)) {
        // wait for onActivityResult call (see below)
    } else {
        String str = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(code);
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationService.class); 
                startService(i); // OK, init GCM
            }
            break;

        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLUS_LOGIN:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                GoogleFragment f = (GoogleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentByTag(GoogleFragment.TAG);
                if (f != null && f.isVisible())
                    f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**GoogleFragment.java:**

```
public class GoogleFragment extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public final static String TAG = "GoogleFragment";

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private ImageButton mLoginButton;
    private ImageButton mLogoutButton;

    public GoogleFragment() {
        // required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google, container, false);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();

        mLoginButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLogoutButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
        mLogoutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    private void googleLogin() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void googleLogout() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mLoginButton)
            googleLogin();
        else
            googleLogout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Person me = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (me != null) {
            String id = me.getId();
            Person.Name name = me.getName();
            String given = name.getGivenName();
            String family = name.getFamilyName();
            boolean female = (me.hasGender() && me.getGender() == 1);

            String photo = null;
            if (me.hasImage() && me.getImage().hasUrl()) {
                photo = me.getImage().getUrl();
                photo = photo.replaceFirst("\\bsz=\\d+\\b", "sz=300");
            }

            String city = "Unknown city";
            List<Person.PlacesLived> places = me.getPlacesLived();
            if (places != null) {
                for (Person.PlacesLived place : places) {
                    city = place.getValue();
                    if (place.isPrimary())
                        break;
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Given: " + given + ", Family: " + family + ", Female: " + female + ", City: " + city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // ignore? don't know what to do here...
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), MainActivity.REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLUS_LOGIN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            int code = connectionResult.getErrorCode();
            String str = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(code);
            Toast.MakeText(getContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```